# move mouse to position using geckodriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, intern, geckodriver

I'm using intern testing with Selenium to automate the functional tests ([link](https://theintern.github.io/intern/#what-is-intern)).

And we need to be able to run against multiple browsers. So we focused more on *Chrome*, but also we were able to run the tests against *IE* and *Firefox*, but after `geckodriver` was released and we switched to it, most of the tests that are implying mouse events are failing, for example when I'm calling `moveMouseTo()` I'm getting the following Exception:

```
Executing: [mousemove: 7 false])
WARN - Exception thrown
org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: mouseMoveTo
```

I've found a similar question about hovering on an element and I managed to make it work with intern by executing the code from `moveMouseTo` function like we had the mouse events broken, so I just commented that if related to `brokenMouseEvents`

```
//if (this.capabilities.brokenMouseEvents) {
   if(element){
      return element.getPosition().then(function(position){
            return self.execute(simulateMouse, [ {
                        action: 'mousemove',
                        position: position,
                        element: element,
                        xOffset: xOffset,
                        yOffset: yOffset
                    } ]).then(function (newPosition) {
                        self._lastMousePosition = newPosition;
                    });
                })
    } else{
           return self.execute(simulateMouse, [ {
                action: 'mousemove',
                position: self._lastMousePosition,
                element: element,
                xOffset: xOffset,
                yOffset: yOffset
            } ]).then(function (newPosition) {
                self._lastMousePosition = newPosition;
            });
      }
//}
```

But doing this breaks the scrolling, since `moveMouseTo()` can be used also to scroll for an element and also we cannot use it since the `moveMouseTo()` function is defined in node modules, and it will fail when we try to run the tests in `Jenkins`.
Another idea, I think it will be to build a wrapper function to treat the case when we're running against *Firefox*, and in that case we should execute another code, and for the other browsers we can call `moveMouseTo()`, but in this case I'm not sure how to fix the scrolling issues.

Does anyone have any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think to move to an element you can use `Actions` class

```
Actions ac= new Actions(driver);
ac.movetoElement().build().preform();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to move to an element:

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript(arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", webElement);
```